# How can I determine reuseIdentifier of a cell inside the heightForRowAtIndexPath method?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell, heightforrowatindexpath

I've got two different types of cells. I need to assign different sizes for each of them in method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

How can i determine the type of cell? Maybe get its reuseIdentifier or etc.

**Update**
When I try this

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]);
}
```

I receive an exception 
[image]

Comment: You should not try to get cell using cellForRowAtIndexPath: method in heightForRowAtIndexPath: method, because it will create endless loop and exception.

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine each cell from object which you get from _messages array.

`id object = _messages[indexPath.row];`

Comment: I wanted to know how to obtain reuseIdentifier and totally forgot that i've got another way to determine cells type. Thanks!